# 8-Bit Program Counter Implementation

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, counter, cpu, logisim

I'm trying to construct an 8-Bit Program Counter, in Logisim. It currently has functions LOAD, which makes the 8-Bit input (A0-A7) appear at the output (S0-S7) on the clock pulse:

Loading 1 as input:
[image: LOAD 1]

1 successfully loaded/stored:
[image: LOAD 2]

When LOAD is high, A0-A7 is run through the full adder, which technically is used - it just adds 0, so therefore doesn't affect the output.

Now I'm trying to implement an INC (increment) also, which when high will basically just add 1, but take the current register value as the input, rather than A0-A7. Here is the logic flowing in the simulation, which is exactly what I want (I've circled the value going into the register, which is 2 - perfect):
[image: INC]

However, now when I try to store this value in the register by pulsing the clock - I get an 'oscillation detected' error in Logisim:
[image: ERROR]

This is the first time I've tried to build this, so is there something intrinsically wrong with my implementation, or am I missing something small which should make it perform as expected?

Comment: Can you put some labels on your inputs/outputs for the full adder and mux? I suspect that you are getting a circular dependency in that the adder is trying to add 1 to the output of the register, which is presenting the adder with new inputs via the mux, but it's hard to tell without labels!

Comment: Do you have any documentation on that "register"? I can only see some kind of problem there if a) that's a transparent register (outputs follow inputs as long as the "clock" is high) or b) the simulator cannot calculate that loop even tough it's not an invalid real world situation.

Comment: @srl100 Of course, slipped my mind entirely. Now updated!

Comment: @RaphaelP An abstraction of the register would be: Output = Input when LOAD is high AND CLK is pulsed. Output is stored/persistent in all other states, regardless of inputs.

Comment: Does this register have any attributes/properties that change the way it behaves?

Comment: It does not. However, if I hold CLK and LOAD high, then change the input, it reflects directly in the output. Should this only be the case once per pulse (rising edge) as oppose to consistently when CLK is high?

Comment: If your register's docs are these
http://www.cburch.com/logisim/docs/2.3.0/libs/mem/register.html
Then you'd want to check if "Trigger" isn't set to "high level".
@ your last comment: that's exactly the problem. If you can't change that behavior then you'll have to change a bit the circuit.

Comment: I actually designed the D-Type Flip-Flops myself, which I now realise act as 'high level', rather than 'rising edge triggered'! This just creates an infinite counting loop, hence the 'oscillating' error. Thankyou so much for the insight, I hadn't even considered this. Happy to accept as answer if you'd like to post it.

Comment: Did you know you can bundle up to 32 wires into one wire in Logisim? It makes the schematic less cluttered.

Comment: @immibis I do, this diagram was just for a bit more clarity. Cheers for the tip however!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your register is propagating it's output based on the "clock" level and not it's transition (aka transparent register), which is creating an unstable loop. For that circuit to work, you'd have to:

- Change that part to a register that changes it's outputs only at the clock's transition from low to high.

or

- Add a second register after the first that's clocked by the inverse of the first one's clock. By doing so, your circuit still takes 1 clock to output the changes to the bus, but it does so in two steps, preventing the register's changing output from affecting it's own input.